# How to get a page access token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, token

I want to generate a page access token with graph API 5.0 and don't know how to do.

I have an app, linked to a page which I am administrator, with all the permissions I need.
Everything works fine inside the graph API explorer.

The documentation says I need a user access token in order to get the page access token, using `https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/me/accounts?access_token=$user_access_token`.

The problem is I don't know how to get it programmatically without having to confirm in the facebook popup. All I have now is the app access token, but this is an invalid parameter this endpoint.

Does somebody know where I'm wrong?

Comment: You can't. You can't get a user access token without the user manually allowing your app. And if you don't have a user access token you can't get  page access token.

Comment: So I can't get the app owner user token ?

Comment: Sure if the app owner goes through the login flow manually.